# Scroll event still working after removeEventListener was called

Tags: javascript, typescript, lit

I'm working with lit-element, and have some places where need to add a scroll listener and run some functions so decided to create a 'service' for that, that will addEventListener and can take a function as callback. And while call `unsubscribeDomEvents()` it should removeEventListener.

So base functionality is working, but removeEventListener is not. I still can see this console from `_onScroll()`, even after `unsubscribeDomEvents()` was called. Here's what I have now:

```
const SCROLL_DOWN = 'scrollDown';

export class ScrollManager {
  private container: HTMLElement;
  private _callbacks = [];
  private readonly _scrollBind;

  constructor({ container }) {
    this._scrollBind = this._onScroll.bind(this);
    this.container = container;
    this.container.addEventListener('scroll', this._scrollBind);
  }

  onScrollDown(callback): ScrollManager {
    return this._registerCallback(SCROLL_DOWN, callback);
  }

  unsubscribeDomEvents(): void {
    this.container.removeEventListener('scroll', this._scrollBind);
  }

  private _registerCallback(callbackType: string, callback): ScrollManager {
    this._callbacks[callbackType] = callback;
    return this;
  }

  private _isScrollToBottom(container: HTMLElement): boolean {
    return container.scrollHeight - container.scrollTop - container.clientHeight < 1;
  }

  private _onScroll(): void {
    console.log('onscroll');
    if (this._isScrollToBottom(this.container)) {
      this._callbacks[SCROLL_DOWN]();
    }
  }
}
```

And here's how I use it in component

```
stateChanged(state: IState): void {
    ...
    this.isEditMode = state.modes.isEditMode;
    
    if (this.isEditMode) {
      this._scrollManager = new ScrollManager({ container: this.container })
              .onScrollDown(this.onScrollDown.bind(this));
    } else {
      this._scrollManager?.unsubscribeDomEvents();
    }

    this.requestUpdate();
  }

private onScrollDown(): void {
      // some function
}
```

Would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### For future Googlers

You are correctly avoiding a common mistake here:

```
this._scrollBind = this._onScroll.bind(this);
```

Where you keep a reference to the original bound function and unsubscribe that:

```
this.container.removeEventListener('scroll', this._scrollBind);
```

*otherwise you will be attempting to unsubscribing another function*

##### Your case

Observe your `stateChanged` function, if it fires more than once while `isEditMode` is truish, then you will instantiate `ScrollManager` twice, but unsubscribe once.

This is what I believe is the correct form:

```
stateChanged(state: IState): void {
  ...
  this.isEditMode = state.modes.isEditMode;
  this._scrollManager?.unsubscribeDomEvents();
  if (this.isEditMode) {
    this._scrollManager = new ScrollManager({ container: this._scrolableContainer })
      .onScrollDown(this.onScrollDown.bind(this));
  }
  this.requestUpdate();
}
```